# python any() works differently , why any([1,2]) in [1,3,5] returns True but not any(['a','b']) in ['a','v','x']?

Tags: python, any

```
any([1,2]) in [1,3,5]
```

output is `True` which is right but

```
any(['a','b']) in ['a','v','x']
```

gives `False` which is wrong ??
why this behavior in python.??

Comment: `True in [1,3,5]` >> `1 in [1,3,5]`

Comment: This doesn't do what you're thinking at all. The first one is actually doing `True in [1, 3, 5]`!

Comment: You're not using the `any()` function correctly.

Comment: maybe you meant `any(x in [1,3,5] for x in [1,2])`

Comment: You can't bypass loop.

Comment: `any([1,2]) in [1,3,5]` does not mean "Are any of the values `[1,2]` present in `[1,3,5]?"`  You're using the `any()` function the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are actually two operations:

first evaluate 'any' and then check if the result is in the other list:

```
any(list) --> is there any item in the list that is equivalent to True?

any([1, 2]) --> True, any non-zero integer is equivalent to True!
any(['a', 'b']) --> True, any character is equivalent to True!
```

Then

```
is the result (True) in [1, 3, 5]? --> Yes! 1 and True are actually the same!
is the result (True) in ['a','v','x']? --> No! True (or 1) is not in the list
```

You can resolve your problem using 'set':

```
set([1, 2]) & set([1, 3, 5]) --> set([1]) --> True, any non-empty set is equivalent to True!

set(['a','b']) & set(['a','v','x']) --> set(['a']) --> True, any non-empty set is equivalent to True!
```

As in the comments, Python makes implicit conversion to bool ('a' --> True) when using 'any' but does exact match (1 is like an internal representation for True) when using 'in'.

Answer (score 2):

**`any(x)` returns `True` if and only if any of the elements of `x` evaluate to `True`.**

So, `any([1,2]) in [1,3,5]` first evaluates `any([1, 2])` which is `True`, since `1` is 'Truthy', and then does `True in [1, 3, 5]`.

`True in [1, 3, 5]` is `True` because `in` tests the equality of items with whatever is before the `in`. Since, in Python, `True == 1`, `True` really is in `[1, 2, 3]`

Therefore `any([1,2]) in [1,3,5]` is `True`!

**So why is the second one `False`?**

This is because of the difference between 'truthiness' and equivalence.

`any(['a', 'b'])` is also `True`. Since `bool('a') == True`, 'a' is **'truthy'**. **However**, `True != 'a'`, so it falls down at the second part, because `'a'` and 'True' are not **equivalent** That is, `True` is not in `['a', 'v', 'b']`.

Comment: Note that "True in [2]" is False

Comment: Indeed, edited.

Answer (score 1):

The correct any usage would be:

```
>>> any(x in ['a','v','x'] for x in ['a', 'b'])
True
>>> any(x in ['a','v','x'] for x in ['ea', 'b'])
False
```

You need to check elementwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is being evaluated in 2 parts...

`any(['a','b'])` is `True`, as is `any([1,2])`. So you're really asking python "Is `True` in the following list?"

You just happen to get lucky in the first example that `1` is treated by python as equivalent to `True`, so as far as it's concerned, `True` *is* in `1, 2, 3`

Try... `any(1, 2, 3) in (3, 4)` ... False. Because `1` isn't in the second list.

Comment: 2 is also 'truthy'. As in `bool(2) == True`

Comment: True [pun intended] but all that means is that _anything_ in the left `any()` will evaluate to True.  `2 == True` is false, which is what the `in` is doing

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `any()` correctly.

`any()` takes an iterable, and if any of the values in the iterable are truthy, it returns True, otherwise it returns False.

So, in your first example:

```
any([1,2]) in [1,3,5]
```

You're calling `any()` on the simple iterable `[1,2]`, and any nonzero number is truthy, so `any()` returns `True`.

`True` happens to have an integer value of 1, so your statement is equivalent to `1 in [1,3,5]`, which is true.

You actually wanted this:

```
any(x in [1,3,5] for x in [1,2])
```